# How to find $y'(x=1)$ in parametric equation?

Tags: calculus, parametric

Given parametric equation
\begin{align}
x(t)&=a-b(2t+\sin(2t))\\
y(t)&=b(1+\cos(2t))
\end{align}
and
$y(x=0)=1$.

Find $y'(x=1)$.

This is my effort.

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx(t)}{dt}}\\
&=\dfrac{-2b\sin(2t)}{-b(2+2\cos(2t))}\\
&=\dfrac{\sin(2t)}{1+\cos(2t)}
\end{align}

Now I confused to find $y'$ in variable $x$, because the parametric equation cannot explicitly express $y$ in $x$. So I can't find $y'(1)$. Anyone can give me hint to solve this problem?

Comment: $$y = - \frac{1}{2} \frac{dx}{dt}$$ Else, you can invert the $y$ equation to get $$t = \frac{1}{2} \arccos \left( \frac{y}{b} - 1 \right)$$

Comment: Your dy/dx is wrong. It should be dy/dx = (dy/dt)/(dx/dt).